# Facebook SDK - Error inflating class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I just installed the Facebook SDK to my app. Now I want to display the FB Log In Button and now I got this error:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
```

this is very weird since I can already see the FB button on my phone. I can see the activity for 1 second, and then it crashes.

this is the xml:

```
    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/signInFacebook"
        />
```

this is the java activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);
}
```

this is the app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.stanleysantoso.app"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
sourceSets { main { res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res/anim'] } }
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
//compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.5.1'
compile project(':libraries:facebook')
}
```

this is the facebook build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

project.group = 'com.facebook.android'

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'


}

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc2"


defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        //resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
}

apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'signing'

def isSnapshot = version.endsWith('-SNAPSHOT')
def ossrhUsername = hasProperty('NEXUS_USERNAME') ? NEXUS_USERNAME : ""
def ossrhPassword = hasProperty('NEXUS_PASSWORD') ? NEXUS_PASSWORD : ""

task setVersion {
// The version will be derived from source
project.version = null
def sdkVersionFile = file('src/com/facebook/FacebookSdkVersion.java')
sdkVersionFile.eachLine{
    def matcher = (it =~ /(?:.*BUILD = \")(.*)(?:\".*)/)
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        project.version = matcher[0][1]
        return
    }
}
if (project.version.is('unspecified')) {
    throw new GradleScriptException('Version could not be found.', null)
}
}

uploadArchives {
repositories.mavenDeployer {
    beforeDeployment { MavenDeployment deployment -> signing.signPom(deployment) }

    repository(url: "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/") {
        authentication(userName: ossrhUsername, password: ossrhPassword)
    }

    snapshotRepository(url: "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/") {
        authentication(userName: ossrhUsername, password: ossrhPassword)
    }

    pom.project {
        name 'Facebook-Android-SDK'
        artifactId = 'facebook-android-sdk'
        packaging 'aar'
        description 'Facebook Android SDK'
        url 'https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk'

        scm {
            connection 'scm:git@github.com:facebook/facebook-android-sdk.git'
            developerConnection 'scm:git@github.com:facebook/facebook-android-sdk.git'
            url 'https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk'
        }

        licenses {
            license {
                name 'Facebook Platform License'
                url 'https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/LICENSE.txt'
                distribution 'repo'
            }
        }

        developers {
            developer {
                id 'facebook'
                name 'Facebook'
            }
        }
    }
}
}

uploadArchives.dependsOn(setVersion)

signing {
required { !isSnapshot && gradle.taskGraph.hasTask("uploadArchives") }
sign configurations.archives
}

task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
// JDK 1.8 is more strict then 1.7. Have JDK 1.8 behave like 1.7 for javadoc generation
if (org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm.current().getJavaVersion() == JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8) {
    options.addStringOption('Xdoclint:none', '-quiet')
}
}

task androidJavadocsJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: androidJavadocs) {
classifier = 'javadoc'
from androidJavadocs.destinationDir
}

task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
classifier = 'sources'
from android.sourceSets.main.java.sourceFiles
}

artifacts {
archives androidSourcesJar
archives androidJavadocsJar
}

afterEvaluate {
androidJavadocs.classpath += project.android.libraryVariants.toList().first().javaCompile.classpath
}
```

and this is the setting.gradle:

```
include ':app'
include ':libraries:facebook'
```

Please help me out here. Thank you very much.

**EDIT**

I am also getting this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.containsKey(ConcurrentHashMap.java:911)
        at com.facebook.internal.Utility.queryAppSettings(Utility.java:825)
        at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$1.run(LoginButton.java:489)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

and they point to this code:

in LoginButton.java:

```
private void checkToolTipSettings() {
    switch (toolTipMode) {
        case AUTOMATIC:
            // kick off an async request
            final String appId = Utility.getMetadataApplicationId(getContext());
            FacebookSdk.getExecutor().execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    final FetchedAppSettings settings = Utility.queryAppSettings(appId, false);
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            showToolTipPerSettings(settings);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            break;
        case DISPLAY_ALWAYS:
            String toolTipString = getResources().getString(
                    R.string.com_facebook_tooltip_default);
            displayToolTip(toolTipString);
            break;
        case NEVER_DISPLAY:
            break;
    }
}
```

in Utility.java:

```
// main thread.
public static FetchedAppSettings queryAppSettings(
        final String applicationId,
        final boolean forceRequery) {
    // Cache the last app checked results.
    if (!forceRequery && fetchedAppSettings.containsKey(applicationId)) {
        return fetchedAppSettings.get(applicationId);
    }

    JSONObject response = getAppSettingsQueryResponse(applicationId);
    if (response == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return parseAppSettingsFromJSON(applicationId, response);
}
```

Comment: I don't think I follow. Could you post some code?

Answer (score 3):

**Put this code into the application tag in Manifest.xml**

```
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You're Facebook SDK isn't importing.  Try to follow the directions on the developer website as they probably have changed since the video tutorial of mine you watched.

Comment: I don't understand how to import according to their direction. That's why I followed your tutorial. If I followed their instruction, I don't know where to put the facebook sdk folder. It's not made in a .jar format

Comment: I also believe fcebook SDK has been imported since I am able to import facebook in the activity.java and also use facebook widgets in the xml. I can even see the facebook blue log in button.